# http.Handler value in argument to r.Handle: missing method ServeHTTP error

Tags: go, server, gorilla, mux

I was trying to build basic web API using gorilla mux in Go. Here is my code. Please help me understand how some interfaces are working here.

````
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views/")))
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))

    r.Handle("/status", myHandler).Methods("GET")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)

}

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)

} ```


error :- `cannot use myHandler (value of type func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)) as http.Handler value in argument to r.Handle: missing method ServeHTTP `
````

Comment: You don't seem to use it in a correct way: the examples clearly state that you need to use "r.HandleFunc" to set handlers and finally use "http.Handle(path, r)"

Comment: You want to use HandleFunc("/status... instead of Handle("status....

Comment: yes sir i found my mistake i was following wrong tutotial @ https://auth0.com/blog/authentication-in-golang/#Building-an-API-in-Go. thanks for your quick repsonse.

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs for mux.Router.Handle](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Handle) show, it takes a [http.Handler](https://godoc.org/net/http#Handler). This is an interface with a single method: `ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)`.

This is useful if you want to pass an object as a handler.

To register the function `myHandler`, use [mux.Router.HandleFunc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.HandleFunc) instead:

```
r.HandleFunc("/status", myHandler)
```

This is also shown in the basic [examples](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux) of the mux package.

Comment: yess exactly, i literally asked this question and later saw it on some other question. actually i was following this tutorial https://auth0.com/blog/authentication-in-golang/#Building-an-API-in-Go that is why it went wrong. Thanks alot for such a quick response.